# Why does Internet Explorer register a click event when I select text from a TextColumn in a GWT CellTable?

Tags: internet-explorer, events, gwt, click

As it says in the title - if you select text in a TextColumn inside a GWT CellTable in IE, it registers a click event when you release the mouse button and the cursor is still inside the cell. In Chrome the click event is not registered. Is there any way to force IE to behave like Chrome and not fire these events if text is being selected?

Easiest way to see this in action is to create a new GWT project in Eclipse and choose to generate sample code. Then modify the generated .html page and add the following as the last row in the table:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" id="tableContainer"></td>
</tr>
```

Then add the following at the start of `onModuleLoad()` in your generated module class:

```
CellTable<Object> ct = new CellTable<Object>();
ct.addColumn(new TextColumn<Object>() {
    public String getValue(Object object) {
            return "Select this";
        }
    });
ct.setColumnWidth(0, "250px");
ct.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<Object>() {
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Object> event) {
        if (ClickEvent.getType().getName()
                .equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType()))
            Window.alert("Clicked");
    }
});
ct.setRowData(Arrays.asList(new Object()));
RootPanel.get("tableContainer").add(ct);
```

GWT version I have tried is 2.5; IE versions I have tried are 9 and 11 - behavior remains the same.

Edit: this also happens when plain Javascript is used to add an onclick event to an element and selecting text inside that element. For example, I modified the generated .html page's first row to this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;" id="firstRow">Please enter your name:</td>        
</tr>
```

And added this snipped just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("firstRow").onclick = function() {
        alert("Clicked");
    }
</script>
```

The same thing happens - after I let go of the left mouse button having selected some of the text in the first row, the onclick event fires in IE. It does not fire in Chrome.

Comment: I think a Selection is also a Click-Event. Is the event fired by MouseDown or MouseUp?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The event always fires when I release the mouse button, so is that by MouseUp?

Comment: Thats a Mouse-Click. There is no difference between selection and Mouseclick. The only difference is, that you move the mouse, while the mouse button is pressed.

Comment: That would mean that IE is right and Chrome is wrong in this case, as the event is not fired in Chrome. Personally I feel that the way Chrome works is more intuitive, but that does not really matter. What matters to me is how I can allow the user to select some text without triggering the on-click event of the underlying container. Is that even possible in IE?